# Convert Date and Time to Date+Timestamp

Tags: r, date, time

I have a dataset with two columns, Date and Time, and I want to convert it into a column containing the Date and Time together as: `"2014-02-01 13:04:05"` for example.

I know the code for doing this is:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This returns a lot of correct values but also NA because of a problem in the dataset.
My problem resides in my dataset that treats `data$Time` as factors and the time range goes from `02:00:00` - `25:59:00`.

So what I want is to cutoff the `data$Time` so if it is over `24:00:00` it adds another day to the date and displays the correct time.

For example:
`"2014-01-31 25:30:00"` will become `"2014-02-01 01:30:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `hms` from lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "2014-01-31 25:30:00" # input

as.Date(x) + hms(sub(".* ", "", x))
```

giving:

```
[1] "2014-02-01 01:30:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the range goes from 2:00 to 25:59, it means that there is a 2 hours difference from the range 00:00 - 23:59... so why don't you just retrieve two hours from your date? For example, "2014-01-31 25:30:00" will become "2014-01-31 23:30:00", isn't it?

If that's what you want, I guess this should work:

> my.lt <- as.POSIXlt("2014-03-09 14:00:00")
>
> my.lt$hour <- my.lt$hour - 2

Comment: Not exactly, My problem is that you can't just subtract 2 hours from the time, but should add another day to the date so the example should do this:
"2014-01-31 25:30:00" will become "2014-02-01 01:30:00"

Comment: Then maybe can you use my.lt$mday?

Comment: I dont understand completely?
 I have over 500.000 lines, so it is not something I can do manually. 
So I was thinking it would be possible to create a LOGIT vector saying if the time is over 24:00:00 hours, which would then say TRUE or FALSE for that. 
Then use that LOGIT vector to add another day whenever it is TRUE.
Can you help me with that?